# Xcode 6.3: Could not load NIB in bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

When compiled using Xcode 6.3 (iOS 8.3 SDK), some nib filenames end up with an extra `~ipad` or `~iphone` in certain circumstances. For example,  `ViewController~ipad.xib` becomes `ViewController~ipad~ipad.nib`. This is causing a crash because the app doesn't expect the compiled nib files to have the double suffix.

Comment: I would take a guess that this is desired behaviour, if you're using Size Classes why would you need to target your xib files using the `~(iphone|ipad).xib` suffix?

Comment: Right—we intended to target our xib files to specific device types. Prior to the release of Xcode 6.3, having size classes enabled in these files didn't cause any problems.

Comment: I suspect it was maybe a bug or design flaw in the previous releases.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**To fix this, uncheck “Use Size Classes” in any affected documents in Interface Builder.**

This appears to be a bug in the version of `ibtool` included with Xcode 6.3 (and the iOS 8.3 SDK). It's happening in the following circumstances:

- You have a device-specific input file `*~(iphone|ipad).xib` with size classes enabled.
- Your deployment target is anything older than iOS 8.0.

I was able to reproduce the problem on the command line:

```
xcrun --sdk iphonesimulator8.3 ibtool --minimum-deployment-target 7.0 --compile ViewController~ipad.nib ViewController~ipad.xib
```

<del>If you're seeing the same behavior, please duplicate [this radar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5049732669898752).</del> This appears to be fixed in the latest Xcode 6.4 beta.

Comment: File bug? Anyone encountering it would appreciate a radar number.

Comment: The only thing I would say is that if you disable Size Classes you will loose any layouts for defined size classes so this solution really only works if you are only using the regular size class for both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: @Camsoft that's correct. We wanted to target our xibs to specific device types, and didn't want size classes enabled. We just didn't think to disable it because it was never a problem prior to Xcode 6.3.

Comment: @jshier thanks for the suggestion—went ahead and filed [a radar](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5049732669898752).

Comment: Even tho it might be a bug, it makes sense. I mean, if you have a xib ending in ~iphone.xib or ~ipad.xib means that you don't want size classes, you instead want to define the layouts in different files. So makes sense to disable it.

Comment: As long as xibs default to using size classes, and after trawling through about forty xibs, I'd say it's a bug alright :)

Answer (score 2):

change ~ to _ in the xib name and specify explicitly the suffix while loading the bundle programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug of Xcode 6.3 when compiling XIB files. In order to workaround the exceptions there are 4 Options:

1. Target your project to iOS 8
2. Use storyboards instead of XIB files
3. Disable Size Classes
4. Handle NIB loading in code

I detailed each of these options in my blog post: http://www.joobik.com/2015/04/fixing-xcode-63-ios-sdk-error-could-not.html