# Could not load NIB in bundle using storyboard

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ios8.3

With the last version of iOs 8.3, I get this error when I run one of my app:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle**

The app has 2 storyboards, one for iPhone (working normally) and the other for iPad (crashing).

I've tried the suggestions of this topic with no results: [Xcode 6.3: Could not load NIB in bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547861/xcode-6-3-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle)

In my case I'm using StoryBoards and I've no flag on "Use size classes".
Until iOs 8.2 the app worked fine.

Is this a iOs 8.3 bugs? Anyone founded a solution?
Thank you!

EDIT: If I use the iPad storyboard on iPhone and the iPhone storyboard on iPad they work! 
I also tried to rename the storyboards, but nothing change.

EDIT 2: The SplitViewController as initial view controller causes the crash! If I move the initial view controller to another view controller the app works!

EDIT 3: Some news: the problem is caused by the MasterViewController of my SplitViewController. I'm using a TabBarController as MasterViewController and it crash with iOs 8.3. If I change the MasterViewController to another view, the app works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by a SplitViewController with a TabBarController as a MasterViewController.
This cause a crash in iOs 8.3.
I replaced the TabBarController with buttons and now the app is working.

I hope this informations may help someone.

Answer (score 2):

If you have done it programmatically then change ~ to _ in the xib name and specify explicitly the suffix while loading the bundle programmatically.Hope it may help you.

Comment: Thank you, but i'm using a storyboard, not a xib. I also tried to rename the storyboard, but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I was returning nil in the required `init?` method

```
required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    return nil
}
```

because I thought only the method `init(frame:)` was going to be called. Moving the initialization code to `viewDidMoveToWindow` and removing both init methods solved the problem.