# could not load NIB in bundle ios 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

my app was working fine on all device and ios versions. howewer with ios 8.3 app didn't work on ipad.

error is this;

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'OhJ-0x-Wru-view-REE-bT-45u''

.  In the app there is no xib files . I used storyboard both for ipad and iphone. On the iphone side there is no problem. and my storyboard name is MainStoryboard_ipad  not 'OhJ-0x-Wru-view-REE-bT-45u' .

Any one to help ?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load NIB in bundle using storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805703/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-using-storyboard)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't want to change my app storyboard . Is there any thing that I can do?

Comment: The problem seems to be with an Object with the id `OhJ-0x-Wru-view-REE-bT-45u`, you can try to open the storyboard as source file and try to figure out why it is happening. Search for that id.