# React Native libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create my first react native iOS app.
Currently I'm following [Facebook React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) to get started but unfortunately I've stumbled upon a problem on my first `react-native run-ios`. I can't run inital app properly for some reason.

I'm working on Macbook Air with OSX El Capitan (Version 10.11.5) and latest Xcode (Version 8.0 (8A218a)).

**Screenshot and Error message:**

[Here you can see Window Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDeKj.jpg)

```
2016-09-28 11:06:00.065533 HelloWorld[1589:92816] bundleid: org.reactjs.native.example.HelloWorld, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0
2016-09-28 11:06:00.068463 HelloWorld[1589:92816] subsystem: com.apple.siri, category: Intents, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 1, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-28 11:06:00.131054 HelloWorld[1589:93235] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-28 11:06:00.132294 HelloWorld[1589:93235] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-28 11:06:00.171878 HelloWorld[1589:93231] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-28 11:06:00.222728 HelloWorld[1589:92816] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-28 11:06:00.281 HelloWorld[1589:92816] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/alen/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95895E4B-4F37-4E4B-BE5E-CD9C38966986/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F09DF533-2E7A-411F-9698-DCBE1560C2DD/HelloWorld.app> (loaded)' with name 'Main''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fdab34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ecbb21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe14265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKit                               0x000000011273401a -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 507
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000112736803 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 223
    5   UIKit                               0x000000011232761c -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 75
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000112327c13 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000112326274 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1406
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000112323539 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    9   FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001157b276b __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    10  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001157b25e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    11  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001157b296d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd50311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd3559c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd34a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd34494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000112321db6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000112327f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    18  HelloWorld                          0x000000010e3697ff main + 111
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000113cfc68d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Hope someone will help me with this so I can write some code, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things you can try

- Deleting the ios/android folder and building the project from
  scratch, also deleting the node_modules and installing again
- The error you are getting points to this question:
  [Could not load NIB in bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337337/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle)
- And also this question [Xcode 6.3: Could not load NIB in bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547861/xcode-6-3-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle)
- Try a different device
- Different simulator
- Different target ios version

Considering you are just starting out, start again from scratch, in a different folder, if it doesn't work, it's not react-native related but a problem with your OS or developing software, if you require further assistance, please post the full code of the project.

Comment: **1.** Not working
**2.** Not working
**3.** Not working, tried iPhone 5
**4.** Not working
**5.** Not working, tried 8.3

Comment: Thanks for helping me Gazta! I don't have this option here - http://take.ms/Iogqo

Comment: Updated the answer again

Comment: Ok you will not belive this, I've recorded process of creating initial app to prove you that it will not work in another folder but it worked hahaha look at this http://take.ms/OlRL1

Answer (score 0):

for me this was casing after adding redux compse
composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
    autoRehydrate(),
  )