# Since XCode 6.3 -> Nib could not be loaded

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xib, xcode6.3

I updated my XCode from 6.2 to 6.3 today. I adapted all the swift changes, but when I run the application, I get errors for every NIB I try to load that has `~ipad` or `~iphone`. (NIB could not be loaded)

Nibs that don't have that device modifier load as usual. If I remove the `~iphone` or `~ipad`, the nib can be found again, but obviously thats no solution, because it's an Universal App.

Same goes for every other file type, that I try to load via code e.g. storyboards.

Comment: I am seeing that too...

Comment: Same issue here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530388/loading-xib-with-device-modifier-broken-in-xcode-6-3-ios-8-3-iphone-6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to be related to size classes. You can't have size classes enabled in a file that uses the `~iphone` / `~ipad` device modifier - [Xcode 6.3: Could not load NIB in bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29547861/xcode-6-3-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle)